# Can DVI displays and thunderbolt ports be expected to wake the monitors every time from sleep?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, dvi

I've got a 15-inch MBP Retina. I am using both Thunderbolt ports to drive two third-party monitors via DVI.

Sometimes (at least 3-4 times a week) after the display goes to sleep when I walk away from my desk, when I return one of the monitors won't come back up. OSX acts like it thinks the monitor is still active - it appears in the arrangement dialog and windows are still positioned over there. But the monitor itself says it is not receiving a signal.

The only way I've found to fix this problem is to disconnect *both* Thunderbolt ports and reconnect them. Just reseating the one with the issue does not fix it.

Is there a way to prevent this, or at the very least, fix it without having to constantly unplug-replug both monitors?

Comment: Related: [External display on MacBook Pro Retina (Mountain Lion) remains blank after screen timeout or waking up from sleep](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/60993)

Answer (score 2):

I have this same issue on my iMac 27" (Mid 2011) with one external DVI monitor. I took the iMac into the Apple store and the genius couldn't provide an answer to why this was occurring. I also tried using both Thunderbolt ports and the issue would happen on both. So for now what I did was to not let my iMac go into sleep mode. I set it to just have the display's go to black and when I activate the iMac the external display always comes back. Hoping a future update to Mountain Lion OS X 10.8 will fix this issue.