# External Monitor

Tags: display

My macbook seemed not to recognize the external monitor unless I plug it in after it is turned on.  It then working very well.  Another problem is that I cannot let it go to sleep because the ext. monitor will stay dark again.  Now I am using screen saver to keep it on.
Any solution!

Comment: What model of Macbook, brand and model of external monitor, and video connection (VGA, DVI, Thunderbolt) are you using?

Comment: MacBook 13.3" Aluminium (later 2008) to Samsung S19D150 using Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [External display on MacBook Pro Retina (Mountain Lion) remains blank after screen timeout or waking up from sleep](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60993/external-display-on-macbook-pro-retina-mountain-lion-remains-blank-after-scree)